# Cannot boot Windows guest in VirtualBox without kernel module error

Tags: windows, service, kernel, virtualbox

I'm running Vagrant (1.8.1) + VirtualBox (5.0.12) on Windows 7 and trying to boot up a Windows 7 image (modernIE/w7-ie8). However, I get this error:

```
---------------------------
VirtualBox - Error In supR3HardenedWinReSpawn
---------------------------
<html><b>NtCreateFile(\Device\VBoxDrvStub) failed: 0xc0000034 STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND (0 retries) (rc=-101)</b><br/><br/>Make sure the kernel module has been loaded successfully.<br><br><!--EOM-->where: supR3HardenedWinReSpawn
what:  3
VERR_OPEN_FAILED (-101) - File/Device open failed.

Driver is probably stuck stopping/starting. Try 'sc.exe query vboxdrv' to get more information about its state. Rebooting may actually help.</html>
---------------------------
OK
---------------------------
```

I ran the query command, but the service "is not found".

```
> sc.exe query vboxdrv
[SC] EnumQueryServicesStatus:OpenService FAILED 1060:

The specified service does not exist as an installed service.
```

I tried rebooting, too. Nothing.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

There's something wrong with the installation of VirtualBox (I've been seeing reports of this problem as far back as 4.x). The installer registers an incorrect location for the driver SYS file (the `ImagePath` in this example).

```
PS> Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\system\currentcontrolset\services\vboxdrv


Type         : 1
Start        : 3
ErrorControl : 1
ImagePath    : \??\C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxDrv.sys
DisplayName  : VBox Support Driver
PSPath       : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\system\currentcontrolset\services\vboxdrv
PSParentPath : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\system\currentcontrolset\services
PSChildName  : vboxdrv
PSDrive      : HKLM
PSProvider   : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry
```

The file doesn't exist.

```
PS> Test-Path (Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\system\currentcontrolset\services\vboxdrv).ImagePath
False
```

The actual location requires an extra `drivers\vboxdrv`.

```
PS> Test-Path 'C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\drivers\vboxdrv\VBoxDrv.sys'
True
```

You can update the registered location.

```
PS> Set-ItemProperty HKLM:\system\currentcontrolset\services\vboxdrv -Name ImagePath -Value '\??\C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\drivers\vboxdrv\VBoxDrv.sys'
```

And now you can start the driver/service.

```
> sc.exe start vboxdrv
```

Comment: This happened to me when I upgraded to 5.0.20 today, and this answer was spot-on. Thanks!

Comment: The same issue occurred when updating to VirtualBox 5.1.18 today, from 5.1.14, I believe. The "tests" showed exactly the same results, and your solution made it work again!

Comment: With classic command line: 1. run regedit and change "HKLM:\system\currentcontrolset\services\vboxdrv" property imagePath to "\??\C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\drivers\vboxdrv\VBoxDrv.sys", 2. run cmd as admin: "sc start vboxdrv" (without admin says access denied), 3. virtualbox should now work

Comment: If you install Virtualbox in say `C:\Users\...\VirtualBox` then you should look for the `...\drivers\vboxdrv\VBoxDrv.sys` file under your custom installation location and set `Set-ItemProperty ...` accordingly as described above.

Comment: This fix worked for me. Windows 10 Virtualbox 5.1.26 r117224 (Qt5.6.2)

Comment: The same issue happened when I upgraded to 5.2.8.  Followed the steps.  And it worked.  Thanks!

Comment: For the ones that cannot fix this problem following the above instructions, they should consider uninstalling certain software that are conflicting with virtualbox. That's what I did after reading the above page. It was not the same software. I uninstalled three of the software I installed recently. Hope it helps, guys! https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/17640

Comment: If this doesn't work for you check the below answer with a more upvotes, that's sorted out the issue for me! Be nice to put a note in the answer as well Anthony, just in case that helps others

Comment: @Anthony Mastrean bruh you're a life saver thanks :D

Comment: I tried everything that was said on most platforms but none of it worked. So the only solution that worked was to reinstall the VirtualBox-6.1.26-145957-Win version of VirtualBox (I just downgrade it. the installed version was VirtualBox-6.1.28-145957-Win)

Answer (score 195):

I am on windows 10 and following steps works for me:

Steps:

1. Navigate to "C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\drivers\vboxdrv"
2. Right click on "VBoxDrv.inf" file and select Install option
3. Open the Console as a administrator and run the following command

   ```
   sc start vboxdrv
   ```

Comment: Just had the same issue! This worked for VirtualBox 5.1.6 version.

Comment: Confirmed to work on Windows 10 Pro running VirtualBox 5.1.8

Comment: I tried your solution on Windows 7, VB 5.1.22. But after executing the command, its showing error "A device attached to the system not functioning". Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: OpenService Failed 5 : access is denied

Comment: Worked on Windows 10 after upgrade to VirtualBox 5.1.24

Comment: Worked for me in Windows 7, Virtualbox 5.1.24.

Comment: This working, but the VM Virtual box must be run in Administrator mode.

Comment: Worked Win 10 running 5.2.8.  Thanks!!

Comment: Worked for me on Win 7 host after upgrading from VirtualBox 5.2.18 to 5.2.20.

Comment: I tried `sc start vboxdrv` with no success, I'm using 5.2.26
I had to remove virtualbox and reinstall it again

Comment: It helped after latest choco upgrade.

Comment: Sorted it for me on Win 10 as well! Will put a comment in the accepted answer to point down here

Comment: Worked like a charm. Remember to reboot after install.

Answer (score 8):

Try the following code (as administrator):

```
 sc.exe start vboxdrv
```

Comment: This worked in my case because the kernel driver was installed but its state was "STOPPED", otherwise you have to install it following the other answers.

Answer (score 7):

I did what Anthony Mastrean suggested but I was still getting some errors:

```
C:\Vagrant>sc query vboxdrv

SERVICE_NAME: vboxdrv
        TYPE               : 1  KERNEL_DRIVER
        STATE              : 1  STOPPED
        WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 31  (0x1f)
        SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)
        CHECKPOINT         : 0x0
        WAIT_HINT          : 0x0

C:\Vagrant>sc start vboxdrv
[SC] StartService FAILED 123:

The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

[This thread](https://superuser.com/questions/851227/virtualbox-4-3-20-stops-working-after-windows-update) on superuser gave me the solution:

> find *C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\drivers\vboxdrv\ **VBoxDrv.inf***
>   right click and select Install

Answer (score 4):

---

```html
> vboxmanage --version
7.0.6r155176

Fix:
C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\drivers\vboxsup\VBoxSup.inf # Right Click to install
> sc.exe query vboxsup
> sc.exe start vboxsup
```

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out, there seems to be a file-path issue after upgrades, especially when the VBox was open. The question's keyword was not giving any working results for me here, as I could not even find the directory **/xboxdrv/** and even the file **VBoxDrv.inf** so I changed to **missing xboxdrv** and I found quick **windows_approach** here https://stackoverflow.com/a/32077300/5922263. It simply says that head to the program list, right-click **Oracle VM VirtualBox** and click **Repair** and this time, ensure it is closed first:

```
ControlPanel > Programs > Programs and Features > Oracle VM VirtualBox
```

I hope this helps.